# Sigaction returning -1 on declaration in a child process

Tags: c

<strike>In pong, the code returns the error print.</strike> I know I don't understand enough about signals so I definitely don't know what's going wrong here.

From what I understand, Sigaction returns -1 when:

- The signal is invalid or can't be caught or ignored
- SA_SIGINFO bit flag is set without support from the implementation

<strike>Since SIGUSR1 is a user-defined signal, I don't see why it can't be caught or ignored. Also, I haven't touched SA_SIGINFO, so unless it defaulted to and invalid setting, I can't see why that'd be an issue.</strike>

My project outline says that I need to "Set up a signal handler to call the handler function" within the pong() function, not main. However, Main should send the signal before it ends. The signal function should only print "pong ending" and exit to break the infinite loop inside pong.

Edit 3: The main method isn't sending the signal to `pong()` and the code is left hanging.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int ping();
int pong();
void handle_SIGUSR1(int signum);

int fdA[2];
int fdB[2];
int ppid;


int ping ()
{
    close(fdA[0]);
    close(fdB[1]);
    int i = 0, check = 0;
    printf("ping - %d\n", i);
    write(fdA[1], &i, sizeof(int));
    while (i < 18)
    {
            read(fdB[0], &i, sizeof(int));
            i++;
            printf("ping - %d\n", i);
            write(fdA[1], &i, sizeof(int));
    }
    close(fdA[1]);
    close(fdB[0]);
    exit(0);
    return 0;

}

int pong()
{
    ppid = getpid();
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = handle_SIGUSR1;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("error -> sigaction err\n");
    }
    
    int j = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        read(fdA[0], &j, sizeof(int));
        j++;
        printf("pong - %d\n", j);
        write(fdB[1], &j, sizeof(int));
    }
}

void handle_SIGUSR1(int signum)
{
    printf("Pong ending...\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main ()
{
    if (pipe(fdA) == -1 || pipe(fdB) == -1)
        return 1; // pipe initialization error

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        ping();
    }
    else
    {
        ppid = getpid();
        pong();
    }
    kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);
}
```

Comment: You've not set the signal mask, `sa.sa_mask`, so it is random garbage, and presumably, the random garbage is not acceptable.  Writing `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);` before the call might fix the problem — it would fix the problem if my analysis is correct.  Basically, you have to make sure you've initialized the structure properly/thoroughly.

Comment: With the code edited as you suggested, and as the code above shows, the if statement is still printing the error message.

Comment: Oh, of course! … Take a good look at the `if` statement: `if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1);` — what's the semicolon doing?  Don't put semicolons there; it means that the code block after it is executed unconditionally.  Note that errors should be written to `stderr`, and you could consider using `perror()`, or using `errno` and `strerror()` to report the error message (possibly and number).  But the semicolon is the main problem.  You should still make sure the structure passed to `sigaction()` is fully initialized.

Comment: That works! However, the kill function I've added in `main()` doesn't send the signal correctly. We haven't touched stderr in our class for some reason, however I've seen it come up a number of times. The following code shows how I've implemented the kill function. I have a feeling I'm not sending it to the correct process.

Comment: After moving around `getpid()`, the kill function works as intended! Thanks for the help! I don't see an option to accept your response as an answer. Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the statement(s)  `#include <stdio.h>`  for the function: `printf()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `while (i < 18)`  What is the 'magic' number `18`?  Suggest using a `enum` or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name.  Then use that meaningful name throughout the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring the gist of my comments into an answer.*</sup>

Study the POSIX specification of [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) carefully.

One part of your problem may be that you've not set the signal mask, `sa.sa_mask`, so it is random garbage, and presumably, the random garbage is not acceptable. Writing [`sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigemptyset.html) before the call might fix the problem — it would fix the problem if my analysis is correct. Basically, you should make sure you've initialized the structure properly/thoroughly.  Even if this is not the cause of the trouble, you should still always set the mask.  It isn't a good idea to block a random set of signals; you should know what you're blocking, so either `sigemptyset()` or [`sigfillset()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigfillset.html) should be used to set the mask — or you can ensure the `struct sigaction` structure is zeroed when you create it.

(Similarly, you should ensure the that the `sa_flags` member is appropriately set too — part of the previous point about setting the structure properly. This was noted by [Nate Eldridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64674873/15168).  You should only set one of `sa_handler` and `sa_sigaction`, depending on whether you set `SA_SIGINFO` in the `sa_flags`.)

However, you have another more major problem.  Take a good look at the `if` statement:

```
if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1);
```

What's the semicolon doing? Don't put semicolons there; it means that the code block after it is executed unconditionally.

Note that errors should be written to `stderr`, and you could consider using `perror()`, or using `errno` and `strerror()` to report the error message (and possibly the error number). But the semicolon is the main problem. You should still make sure the structure passed to `sigaction()` is fully initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sa.sa_flags` is uninitialized so it very likely contains flags that make no sense, causing `sigaction` to fail.  It doesn't "default" to anything except garbage.  If you don't want the behavior of any of the flags, set `sa.sa_flags` to 0.

Comment: Adding "sa.sa_flags = 0;" as the edited code shows, sigaction still returns -1. What else could be going wrong?